# "PLS-00526: A MAP or ORDER function is required" when comparing objects for equality

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, comparison, equality

On Oracle 11gR2, I created a simple PL/SQL object type. When trying to compare two instances for equality/inequality, I get a `PLS-00526: A MAP or ORDER function is required for comparing objects in PL/SQL` error, even if the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#LNPLS01385) clearly states that

> If neither a `MAP` nor an `ORDER` method is specified, then only comparisons for equality or inequality can be performed.

Here is the PL/SQL code example I used to reproduce the error:

```
create or replace type point_t is object (x number, y number);
/

declare
  p1 point_t := point_t(1, 2);
  p2 point_t := point_t(1, 2);
  p3 point_t := point_t(2, 1);
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('p1 = p1 ' || case when p1 = p1 then 'OK' else 'FAIL' end);
  dbms_output.put_line('p2 = p1 ' || case when p2 = p1 then 'OK' else 'FAIL' end);
  dbms_output.put_line('p3 <> p1 ' || case when p3 <> p1 then 'OK' else 'FAIL' end);
end;
/
```

Comment: Interesting. The behaviour does seem to contradict the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if neither `MAP` nor `ORDER` method is specified, you can compare objects for equality or inequality but ONLY in SQL statements, NOT a PL/SQL block directly.

Quote from [Database Object-Relational Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ7095)

> if you do not declare one of these methods, you can only compare objects in SQL statements, and only for equality or inequality.

```
create or replace type point_t is object (x number, y number);
/

select case
        when point_t(1,1) = point_t(1,1) then 'OK'
        else 'FAIL'
       end as cmp_res
  from dual;


set serveroutput on;
declare
  l_p1 point_t := point_t(1,2);
  l_p2 point_t := point_t(1,2);
  l_res varchar2(7) := 'OK';
begin
  select 'FAIL'
    into l_res
   from dual
  where l_p1 != l_p2;  -- put it in the where clause just for the sake 
                       -- of demonstration. Can do comparison in the 
                       -- select list as well.
  dbms_output.put_line('p1 = p2 : ' || l_res);
end;
```

Result:

```
Type created.

CMP_RES
-------
OK     

1 row selected.

p1 = p2 : FAIL
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But if there is a need to compare objects directly in PL/SQL block you need to define object comparison rules(when one object is equal/unequal, greater or less than other object, especially when an object has many properties )  either `MAP` or `ORDER` methods needs to be implemented.